# Add nodes automatically to adjacent objects QGIS

Tags: qgis, nodes

I'm currently using QGIS 3.10.2 A Coruna.

I'm translating an analogue map into QGIS and there are different classes of objects within the same Layer (streets, buildings, properties, etc...).

I just ran a topology check, and I have a lot of errors especially in the overlapping of objects, due to the missing nodes of adjacent features. 
[image]

In the screen shot I try to visualize my problem. The green feature is smaller than the adjacent object (orange) left of it. 
Is there a possibility in QGIS to add nodes automatically to adjancent objects?

Comment: Maybe next time activate snapping when digitizing? Snapping also works when editing nodes.

Comment: Maybe use the GRASS tool `v.clean` under QGIS with different tools : https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_topology_cleaning

Comment: Yes, snapping was activated. There were a great number of objects, mistakes like this are bound to happen when you work manually.

Comment: Did you have topological editing enabled as well as snapping?  As for accumulated past errors you could do as J. Monticolo said and run v.clean in GRASS or perhaps run the Geometry Checker.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm familiar with the topological editing - where would I find that? Running v.clean was a very good idea!

Comment: Thanks John, the topological editing is helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the processing tool "snap geometries to layer". You can use the same layer as Input and Reference if needed, or choose different ones, depending on your layer setup. Then choose a suiting snap tolerance (in CRS units) and the desired behavior from the dropdown menu.

[image]